# Jenkins trigger jobs for each maven submodule

Tags: maven, jenkins, multi-module

I have a maven multimodule project. It has 42 submodules and the build process from scratch takes ~50 mins. When I run maven with the "-T"  parameter, i see that there are 4-5 submodules building in parallel. But since they all are running in the same computer, throughput is not changing much.

So i wrote a maven profile which does not build, but calls groovy script (So that each submodule will call this groovy script instead of building), which in turn uses Jenkins's REST api to build that submodule on a different computer. Since -T option made it possible to build 4-5 submodules at any given time, there are 4-5 jenkins jobs building. This reduced the build time in half.

Now, my question is:

Instead of using a groovy script to trigger Jenkins job with its REST api, Can i use maven libraries in a "parent" jenkinsfile job, who calculates which submodules needs to be built, and triggers new jenkins jobs for each submodule that needs to be built?

Basically i need a maven api that calculates the build order and how can it be parallelized, and use it in Jenkinsfiles

Comment: First how long does it take to build your multi module build? What is really consuming the time? The build or the tests ? Distribution over different nodes means you have to download dependencies between the modules from a repository ...which takes time...and is slower then building the multi module build in on go via (`mvn -T ...`)...

Comment: in total, build takes 50 mins. There are other improvements that i am doing to speed up the build, but paralellization will definetly be faster (As currently, it is building paralell). I just wanted to move the groovy code in maven poms to jenkinsfile.

Comment: Like, can i include maven libraries to jenkinsfile and run a groovy command for each maven submodule.

Comment: This sounds far more convoluted than need be. What's so special about the groovy script; post it? Have you assessed what phase of the builds actually take the the most time; repo cloning, dependency resolution, compilation, unit test, package/deployment, etc.? Do you change all the modules concurrently? Why not build and deploy sub-modules to an artifact repository and rebuild only as needed?

Comment: My company uses intranet and the groovy code is in there. I am not able to post it in here. Im updating the question becaues i think i need to be more clear

Comment: 50 minutes? Which Maven version do you use? Which JDK Version do you use? Also do you use the most recent versions of plugins? Are you running unit- and/or integration tests? How long do the tests take? Are you running the unit test in parallel? How many lines of code? Which kind of build machines you are using? How many CPU's/Core's ? RAM/SDD ? etc. I've ran build with 800+modules within 15 minutes (2.5 million lines of code incl. 20.000 unit tests)... ? That sounds like there are some other issues?

Comment: My company uses maven to reslove dependencies for cpp projects, We use maven exec plugin to call cmake for builds. Of course there are other issues, i just want to know if i can get the build plan for submodules without invoking maven as process, but from a jenkinsfile script.

Comment: @Tinasour you could get the module build order by using the following plugin: https://github.com/starlingbank/reactor-maven-plugin. It generates plain text information that could be used to determine the build plan .